# Is there a flaw in this proof of the Bolzano-Weierstass theorem in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_i) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded sequence.
Let $M \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $|a_i| < M$ for $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.
Fix $\epsilon>0$, then by the Archimedian principle $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $N>\frac{4M}{\epsilon}$.
Let $V_j$ be the $\epsilon$-neighborhood centered at $-M+j\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $j = 0,1,... N$. Based on the choice of $N$ we know that $\bigcup_{j=0}^N{V_j} \supset (-M,M) \supset (a_i)$.
Since there are infinitely many elements in the original sequence and there are only finitely many $V_j$'s at least one of these neighborhoods contains infinitely many elements. Let $(a_{(i_k)} )$ be that infinite subsequence which is in one of the $V_j$'s. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this subsequence is Cauchy and hence converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is not correct. The subsequence depends on $\epsilon$ and is not itself Cauchy since the only property it has is to be contained in an interval of length $\epsilon$...

Instead one should take a sequence of $\epsilon\to 0$ and find a corresponding sequence of $V_j$ and a corresponding subsequence of $a_i$ which will result being Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

No: you have not shown the subsequence to be Cauchy. However small and arbitrarily chosen $\epsilon$ is, there is a non-Cauchy sequence within an interval of width $\epsilon$.